# Change zIndex of Vectors in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, vector, layers, z-index

I have a bunch of linestring features on a vector layer. Some of them overlap. If I trigger the hover event on those features, I want them be in front.
I did find some functions to set the z-index of layers, but nothing for manipulation individual features. I tried using the individual style maps, but that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    // Add vectory layer
    this.vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Track", {
        renderers: ['Canvas', 'SVG', 'VML'],
        rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true },
        styleMap: myStyle
    });
    tbMap.map.addLayer(this.vector);
```

In a loop various lines are added like so:

```
        //make the new tracksegment
        myTrack = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(path), {hash: hash});

        // Draw vector on the layer
        this.vector.addFeatures([myTrack]);
```

And the stylemap:

```
var myStyle = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
        pointRadius: config.pointRadius,
        strokeColor: config.strokeColor,
        fillColor: config.fillColor,
        fillOpacity: config.fillOpacity,
        strokeWeigth: config.strokeWeigth,
        strokeWidth: config.trackWeight,
        strokeOpacity: config.strokeOpacity,
        fontColor: config.fontColor,
        fontSize: config.fontSize,
        fontFamily: config.fontFamily,
        graphicZIndex: 0
    }),
    "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
        pointRadius: config.pointRadius,
        strokeColor: config.strokeColor_selected,
        fillColor: config.fillColor,
        fillOpacity: config.fillOpacity,
        strokeWeigth: config.strokeWeigth,
        strokeOpacity: config.strokeOpacity,
        fontColor: config.fontColor,
        fontSize: config.fontSize,
        fontFamily: config.fontFamily,
        graphicZIndex: 100
    }),
    "hover": new OpenLayers.Style({
        pointRadius: config.pointRadius,
        strokeColor: config.strokeColor_hover,
        fillColor: config.fillColor,
        fillOpacity: config.fillOpacity,
        strokeWeigth: config.strokeWeigth,
        strokeWidth: config.trackWeight,
        strokeOpacity: config.strokeOpacity,
        fontColor: config.fontColor,
        fontSize: config.fontSize,
        fontFamily: config.fontFamily,
        graphicZIndex: 100
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the render intents (select, hover, default) in the stylemap with the [SelectFeature control](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html).

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vLpt6/36/)

```js
var hoverControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    [layer],
    {
        hover: true,
        highlightOnly: true
    }
);
map.addControl(hoverControl);
hoverControl.activate();
```

## UPDATE:

As you can see from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/19418/2022) It only started working when the rendererOptions are moved to the constructor. I know... doesn't make sense, [but it works](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19486/2022).

I striked out the above because you do have renderOptions in the constructor. Just use SelectFeature to acitvate correct renderintents on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I was reading polygons and point features from one WFS call and adding these to a OL Vector layer. 
Some polygons would capture the "hover event" hiding the points "hover event".
My solution was to add all vectors to the layer but send the points to a JS array. 
Later I would add all features of the array to the Vector layer.

layer.addFeatures( pointFeatures, {style: myStyleForPoints});

regards,
Joaquim Muchaxo
Ithaca.pt

Comment: I don't see how this relates to lines overlapping each other and thus blocking the 'hover' of the underlying line. Does your trick somehow help with the zIndexing of the layer?

Comment: I did not realise you were "trigging" the hover event, so you can chose the features to hover. If changing the Z-index does not work, OL is probably ignoring the change, Most Examples and api tests that OL do are static. I think you should destroy and re-create the features or instead of "hovers" you could simples crate popups on line centroid for instance.

Comment: In the meantime I recall I have played with renderIntent. Maybe this can give you a clue https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/562

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest (and probably easiest) way to achieve what you want is to simply add a Vector layer, say it's called *highlight*, on top of all others and then move (or copy) features into this layer as they are selected.